# WebSocket connection error with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, web-service, node-js, amazon-ec2

I am new to OpenLayers and NodeJS. I have installed OpenLayers on my EC2 instance following exactly the instructions found on the OpenLayers website (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html). This includes first installing NPM (using NVM) and then using Parcel to bundle my application.

I am able to render a map on the default port of 1234 on my EC2 instance, but after a few seconds I get the following error message:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://ec2-18-234-227-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com:46141/' failed: Error
>   in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT NOTE that I
>   am using Chrome.

Looking at the the specific line of code that is specified (found here: parcelRequire.node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/builtins/hmr-runtime.js), you will see the following code:

> var ws = new WebSocket(protocol + '://' + hostname + ':' +
>   process.env.HMR_PORT + '/');

This process.env.HMR_PORT variable created by Parcel is what is generating an error message on my EC2 instance (I believe), but I am not sure how best to fix this without introducing new errors.

Any thoughts about how to fix this? I tried the following command which someone suggested to avoid this error but it did not work:

> npm start --no-hmr